# Shopify Sortable new position

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'am trying to update my code from Jquery Sortable to Shopify. It all works well, but iam having some trouble reading the new position in the index, that I need to post to the backend. It looks like it continuous to post the old index value.

Here is my code:

```
        init: function () {
        var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-zone');

        if (containers.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        const sortable = new Sortable.default(containers, {
            draggable: '.draggable',
            handle: '.draggable .draggable-handle',
            mirror: {
                appendTo: 'body',
                constrainDimensions: true
            },
        });
        sortable.on('sortable:start', function(){
            console.log("'swappable:start'");
        });
        sortable.on('sortable:stop', function() {
            console.log('swappable:stop');
            var portlets = $(".containersection");
            var sectionarray = portlets.map(function(i,el){return {uuid:el.getAttribute('data-uuid'), position:el.getAttribute('data-position')}}).get();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(sectionarray));
            //The position in this array reflects the new position we need to send to the backend
            $.ajax({
                url: '/updatepositions',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'post',
                data: { 
                    _csrf: $("input[name=_csrf]").val(),
                    positions: sectionarray
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    toastr.success("The order was saved", "updated");
                  },
                error: function(result) {
                    toastr.error("The order wasn't saved.", "Something went wrong");
                }
              });
        });
    }
```

I suspect the error is within this line:

```
var sectionarray = portlets.map(function(i,el){return {uuid:el.getAttribute('data-uuid'), position:el.getAttribute('data-position')}}).get();
```

But iam not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there isen't a method to receive the array after sorting, according to this issue: https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/issues/273
I will revert back to using jquery sortable instead.